# Backing up an Android app to Google Drive

Tags: applications, google-play-store, backup, google-drive, google-backup

Let's say you've installed an app, but you realize it is no longer available in the Google Play store.

Is there a way to back the app up in Google Drive (so, that, if your phone breaks down and you update your phone to one with a newer version of Android you can still use the app (by downloading it and installing it from Google Drive))?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't have an answer but you could always download the APK from the net. Sites like ApkMirror or uptodown